# how to send post data with http header in php?

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, http-headers, restful-authentication

```
    private function reset_pwd_confirm(){
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
        $verification_id = $this->_request['verification_id']; 
        $user_id = $this->_request['user_id']; 
        if(!empty($verification_id) && !empty($user_id) && $user_id > 0){
            if(md5($user_id) == $verification_id){                                       
                header("Location: http://localhost:3000/#/reset?user_id=".$user_id);
                exit();                
            }else{
                $success = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Not confirmed.");
                $this->response($this->json($success),404);
            }
        }else{
            $success = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Invaild verification or user id.");
            $this->response($this->json($success),404);
        }

    }
```

I'm dealing with Restful apis ,the following apis is used for password reset confirmation, After confirmed api should redirect to                      **"Location: http://localhost:3000/#/reset"** with {user_id:"5"} by post method for re-enter the password and submit with this id.

how to solve this context?
thanks.

Comment: You should send a json response that it was succeeded and let angularjs redirect you to the correct page.

Comment: this apis calling from mail on click, if you say like that then how to run that particular "reset" page via json?
can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Can you show me your angular controller in which you call the API?

Comment: you are asking the controller api for sending mail

Comment: $scope.resetClick = function() {
        $scope.user.error_status = false;
        $scope.user.error = '';        
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: API_CONFIG.url + 'user/send_reset_pwd',
            data: {user:{email:$scope.user.email}}
        }).